# sqoop2 job run error that Table 'api_open_platform.input_data' doesn't exist

Tags: sqoop2

I use sqoop2 to extract data from MySQL. I have set the Schema name when I create a job, but when I run the job, sqoop2 uses the first Schema name in MySQL rather than I set.

this is the setting when I create a job

```
Schema name: investment_estimation
Table name: input_data
```

this is the error message when I run the job

```
Message: GENERIC_JDBC_CONNECTOR_0003: Unable to access metadata -
.
.
Message: Table 'api_open_platform.input_data' doesn't exist
```

api_open_platform is my a database in MySQL

how to solve it, help me, please